# Reset Zebra Css Design with list items

Tags: css, html

I want a zebra design for my list items.But I want to restart my zebra design when I have li with "resetZebra".

I tried this css trick but it doesn't work.

```css
li:not(.select-group-item):nth-child(even){
          background: red;
 }
.resetZebra{
     background: green !important;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="resetZebra">Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li class="resetZebra">Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li class="resetZebra">Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
```

How can I do that trick with css?Any suggestions?

Edit: I want to start with background white list item after the resetZebra items everytime.For example in this dom tree second li must be white and three must be red.

Comment: please provide full code or working fiddle. so we can check

Comment: You need to use javascript for that

Comment: you need to define what you mean by *reset*

Comment: on `resetzebra` what `background color` you want or you don't want any `background` on `resetZebra` element.

Comment: `:nth-selectors` are not available for classes, making this very tricky. You could hardcode it in css but that's not ideal. If you have control over the html it should be easy to work with a different solution. I'm also curious if your current structure makes sense, maybe you should work with nested lists or tables(which can have multiple `tbody`'s)

Answer (score 0):

you can try below solution by changing the colours you need

```js
var nextColor ="#00FF00" ;
$('.zebralist').children().each(function(index,child){
    if($(child).hasClass("resetZebra")){
    nextColor ="#00FF00";
  } else {
    if(nextColor === "#00FF00"){
        child.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
      nextColor = "#FF0000"
    } else{
    child.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
      nextColor = "#00FF00"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="zebralist">
<li class="resetZebra">Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li class="resetZebra">Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li class="resetZebra">Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
```